# NPM ERROR! Deployed ionic app on to heroku however not able to view it, it keeps prompting application error

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, heroku, visual-studio-code, procfile

```
2019-12-31T00:55:15.975348+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-12-31T00:55:15.980947+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-31T00:55:15.981122+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-12-31T00:55:15.981236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-12-31T00_55_15_976Z debug.log
2019-12-31T02:05:58.818659+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T02:05:58.818682+00:00 app[web.1]: > fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start /app
2019-12-31T02:05:58.818684+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2019-12-31T02:05:58.818686+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T02:05:58.824111+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found
2019-12-31T02:05:58.829573+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-12-31T02:05:58.829829+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-12-31T02:05:58.830054+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-12-31T02:05:58.830271+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-12-31T02:05:58.831304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start: `ng serve`
2019-12-31T02:05:58.831503+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-12-31T02:05:58.831749+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-12-31T02:05:58.832016+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start script.
2019-12-31T02:05:58.832374+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-12-31T02:05:58.842595+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T02:05:58.842802+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-12-31T02:05:58.842954+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-12-31T02_05_58_833Z-debug.log
2019-12-31T02:06:08.150928+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T02:06:08.150986+00:00 app[web.1]: > fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start /app
2019-12-31T02:06:08.150988+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2019-12-31T02:06:08.150990+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T02:06:08.160991+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189748+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189763+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189765+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189767+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189789+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start: `ng serve`
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189792+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189799+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189811+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start script.
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189817+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189820+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-12-31T02:06:08.189823+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-12-31T02_06_08_168Z-debug.log
2019-12-31T02:32:20.218397+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T02:32:20.218589+00:00 app[web.1]: > fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start /app
2019-12-31T02:32:20.218598+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2019-12-31T02:32:20.218600+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T02:32:20.223537+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found
2019-12-31T02:32:20.227834+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-12-31T02:32:20.228177+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-12-31T02:32:20.228476+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-12-31T02:32:20.228798+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-12-31T02:32:20.229831+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start: `ng serve`
2019-12-31T02:32:20.230023+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-12-31T02:32:20.230232+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-12-31T02:32:20.230431+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start script.
2019-12-31T02:32:20.230630+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-12-31T02:32:20.238395+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T02:32:20.238518+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-12-31T02:32:20.238606+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-12-31T02_32_20_231Z-debug.log
2019-12-31T03:15:43.240307+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T03:15:43.240323+00:00 app[web.1]: > fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start /app
2019-12-31T03:15:43.240324+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2019-12-31T03:15:43.240326+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T03:15:43.245025+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found
2019-12-31T03:15:43.248619+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-12-31T03:15:43.248868+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-12-31T03:15:43.249074+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-12-31T03:15:43.249294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-12-31T03:15:43.250229+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start: `ng serve`
2019-12-31T03:15:43.250368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-12-31T03:15:43.250547+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-12-31T03:15:43.250678+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the fypjBioP2@0.0.1 start script.
2019-12-31T03:15:43.250811+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-12-31T03:15:43.257022+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-31T03:15:43.257132+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-12-31T03:15:43.257194+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-12-31T03_15_43_251Z-debug.log
```

I have deployed ionic app on to heroku however i am not able to view it, it keeps prompting application error. I am not able to view the app that i have created.

This my first time using ionic and heroku. I have tried to reinstall npm update and run i am still not able to view. It keep saying application error

Comment: The error that you are getting is about `ng` not being found. you should run npm install before that.  Are you able to run this locally? 
In the heroku buildback you should mention `npm install` as a command to run

Comment: i tried but it is still not working, and i am not able to run locally as well